# Parcel-Bundler how to add SVG like how react does it

Tags: reactjs, svg, browser, single-page-application, parceljs

I am using parcel with typescript and out the box everything just works,
Now when I try to include svg it didn't work,

This is because I needed to change in typescript

```
declare module "*.svg"
```

This allows me to now compile my typescript.

Now the other thing that doesn't work is now I want to import my SVG component
and just use it like create-react-app 2

Import Icon from "./icon.svg"

```
function DisplayIcon(){
   return <Icon/>
}
```

So this looked straightforward
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/parcel-plugin-svgr
yarn install and I get Can't resolve

```
 <Typescript file>:<Line>:<Column>: Cannot resolve dependency './icon.svg' at '<Icon Location>'
```

So I think maybe it's the plugin and I try to use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-inlinesvg

I get the same issue.

What is it that I am missing?

I see some people have .babelrc files but the plugins should just work out the box atleast that is what the documentation says.

> Using plugins in Parcel could not be any simpler. All you need to do
>   is install and save them in your package.json. Plugins should be named
>   with the prefix parcel-plugin- or @your-scope/parcel-plugin-, e.g.
>   parcel-plugin-foo or @your-scope/parcel-plugin-foo. Any dependencies
>   listed in package.json with these prefixes will automatically be
>   loaded during initialization.

It seems like the plugins boot, but nothing works.

Without the plugins I get the file in my public path with a string to it in my JavaScript runtime.

What am I missing and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I provided an answer to this question for parcel v2 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472585/4739687 I can't flag this question as a duplicate yet because no one has up-voted my answer yet, but I think it addresses issue (let me know if not).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use an SVG inline in React using Parcel 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944964/how-do-you-use-an-svg-inline-in-react-using-parcel-2)