# How do you use an SVG inline in React using Parcel 2?

Tags: reactjs, svg, parceljs

Previously in Parcel v1 you could just use something like the `@svgr/parcel-plugin-svgr` plugin for Parcel. This would give you the ability to use SVGs inline like when using CRA:

```
import Star from './star.svg'

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Star />
  </div>
)
```

Can anyone help figure out a way to do this in Parcel 2?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#importing-non-code-assets-from-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Parcel2 provides the `@parcel/transformer-svg-react` plugin to accomplish this.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Install it:

   ```
   yarn add @parcel/transformer-svg-react --dev
   ```
2. Add a `.parcelrc` file at the root of your project that defines a named pipleine that uses this plugin:

   ```json
   {
     "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
     "transformers": {
       "jsx:*.svg": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-svg-react"]
       "jsx:*": ["..."]
     }
   }
   ```

   (The `"..."` entry should actually be typed into the `.parcelrc` file - it tells parcel "process these kinds of assets as usual, and only after you are done, transform it into a react component.")

   **Update (5/2022)** I added the `"jsx:*": ["..."]` line, which appears to currently be a necessary workaround to avoid [this bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7587).

   Another current "gotcha" is that if the SVG files that you want to transform into react components contain inline style tags (e.g. `<path style="fill:red" ...>`, you'll run into [this bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7389). To avoid it, you'll want to remove the `@parcel/transformer-svg` plugin from your pipeline by modifiying the first transformer line to read `"jsx:*.svg": ["@parcel/transformer-svg-react"]` (i.e. remove the `...`).
3. Use the named pipeline in your import statements:

   ```
   import Star from 'jsx:./star.svg'

   const App = () => (
     <div>
       <Star />
     </div>
   )
   ```
4. (optional, if you use TypeScript). Let TypeScript know about the `jsx:` named pipeline by using a [wildcard module declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations). In a `d.ts` file that's a part of your typescript project, write this:

   ```
   declare module "jsx:*.svg" {
     import { ComponentType, SVGProps } from "react";
     const SVGComponent: ComponentType<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
     export default SVGComponent;
   }
   ```

See [parcel 2 documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/svg/#importing-as-a-react-component).

Comment: Excellent answer. However if the svg in question is inside node_modules folder it won't work due to this bug https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6748.