# How do I use parcel to build a React component library that imports SVGs?

Tags: reactjs, svg, parceljs

My team works on a React component library that is published as an npm package. The library is built using `parcel`. Here is our `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@parcel/packager-ts": "2.9.3",
  "@parcel/transformer-sass": "2.9.3",
  "@parcel/transformer-svg-react": "2.9.3",
  "@parcel/transformer-typescript-types": "2.9.3",
  "parcel": "2.9.3"
}
```

Our components import SVGs like this:

```
import IconAdd from 'icons/add.svg';
```

We are trying to use `@parcel/transformer-svg-react` to transform our SVGs into JSX.

We followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472585/2262604), so our `.parcelrc` file looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "jsx:*.svg": [
      "...",
      "@parcel/transformer-svg-react"
    ],
    "jsx:*": [
      "..."
    ]
  }
}
```

When we run `parcel build`, the library seems to build correctly, however, when we use the node module in a React application, we get this error:

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('file:///add.878b623c.svg') is not a valid name.
```

We tested the npm package in a new installation of Next.js (13.4.4), as well as a fresh installation of [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev). The same error is seen in both apps.

How can we use `parcel` to `build` our React component library that imports SVGs and then use it as an npm package?

Comment: try import { ReactComponent as IconAdd } from 'icons/add.svg'; and build like here[https://parceljs.org/features/cli/ ]